# While Generating controller and view getting error : Can not set int field lms.Book.bookId to java.lang.Class

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-2.0, grails-controller

While generating controller and view for a Domain class as:

```
class Book {

    static constraints = {
        bookId blank:false
        bookTitle blank:false
    }

    private int bookId
    private String bookTitle
    private String author
    private double price
    private Date edition
    private String publisher
}
```

Giving Error saying : 
Can not set int field lms.Book.bookId to java.lang.Class

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change "int" to "Integer" (and "double" to "Double" too), e.g.

```
class Book {

    static constraints = {
        bookId blank:false
        bookTitle blank:false
    }

    private Integer bookId
    private String bookTitle
    private String author
    private Double price
    private Date edition
    private String publisher
}
```

Also, I doubt whether you can have a "blank" constraint on an Integer, change it to:

```
bookId nullable: false
```

assuming that is what you want (or remove it altogether, as the nullable: false constraint is implicit).

Answer (score 1):

I think if u add 'private' to field declaration, u have to write getter and setter for this field:

```
class Book {

    static constraints = {
        bookId blank:false
        bookTitle blank:false
    }

    private Integer bookId
...
    Integer getBookId() { this.bookId }

    void setBookId(Integer bookId) { this.bookId = bookId }
....
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. You must declare them public or provide the getter/setters yourself. Don't know why this answer isn't marked?